# How to write setters and getters for a doubly linked list in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, getter-setter

When I try to write getNext() method in Node.cpp it gives the below error. Please check in Node.cpp getNext() method.I am trying to write getters and setters for a doubly linked list and here is what i have.

```
class Node

{

    private:

        string phonenumber;
        string name;
        string type;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;

    public:
        Node(string name, string phonenumber, string type);

        void setNext(Node ptr);
        Node getNext();

        string getName();
        void setName(string name);


        string getPhone();
        void setPhone(string phonenum);


        string getType();
        void setType(string type);

};
#endif
```

Node.cpp

```
    #include "Node.h"
    
    Node::Node(string name, string phonenumber, string type)
    {
       //constructor
    }
    
    Node::Node(string name, string phonenumber, string type)
    {
    
    }
    void Node::setNext(Node ptr)
    {
        
    
    }
```

When I try to write getNext() method in Node.cpp it gives the below error. Please check in Node.cpp getNext() method.I am trying to write getters and setters for a doubly linked list and here is what i have.

```
    Node Node::getNext()
    {
    
       return next; /**/ this line gives me an error (it says no suitable constructor exists for Node* to Node)
    }
```

Comment: Note that you have a stray `#endif` in your header file and it's missing `#include <string>` and you probably do `using namespace std;` in the header file which you should never do. You also have two implementations of the same constructor. One must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `next` is a `Node*`, whereas in the function, you are returning a `Node`.
Change `Node` to `Node*`:

```
Node* Node::getNext()
{
   return next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is saying it doesn't know to convert `Node` (an instance of Node) to `Node*` (pointer to an instance of `Node` (or `nullptr`).

These snippets will get you over that hump:

```
//In the class definition:

   Node* getNext();

//... 
// The function definition:

Node* Node::getNext(){
    return this->next;  //or just return next; if you prefer.
}
```

There's a world of difference in C++ between an object and a pointer to that object.

Once you get you head around that concept you've made a huge leap in getting to grips with C++.

I don't know your background but Java buries that point because all object variables are *in effect* pointers (in C++ terms).
But in C++ the distinction is important and you can have an object variable, a pointer or a reference. But pointer is the right answer for `next` and `prev` in a doubly linked-list.

NB: An even better answer is `Node* getNext() const;` but worry about that later!